# Stop Ubuntu from loading GUI

Tags: 14.04, boot, gui

I have read all the other info about this subject but can't get this to work.

I have a Tegra Jetson TK1 board with Ubuntu 14.04 on it, I tried to update and upgrade Ubuntu, but now I can no longer see anything on my screen after the initial start (the list of tasks in text mode and NVidia logo shows up and then the screen goes black).

I tried to hold the shift key while booting, push Ctrl-Alt-F1 among other things, but I can not stop the GUI to load.

Anyone knows hoe I can get a terminal so I can recover the OS?

Really appreciate you help.

Comment: I would try to use a liveusb-stick (or cd) to edit the `/etc/rc2.d` directory to prevent the gui to be loaded. usually it should be runlevel 2, you can try other runlevels, too

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with the Jetson TK1 and upgrading/updating Ubuntu is a known issue. The libglx.so file gets overwritten. You need to run: "sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core" before updating. See wiki page here for more info: http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1#An_important_step_before_connecting_the_Jetson_to_Internet

Apparently this has been solved with the latest TK1 image provided by Nvidia.

I've had the best luck flashing the device using the JetPack. (https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1-development-pack). It requires Ubuntu 12/14 64-bit. And for some reason it takes up a many gigs of disk space and I can't seem to get rid of it even after uninstalling. You might want to take a snapshot before installing if you're using a VM.

Hope that helps.

-Mike

Comment: this might be the better answer.

Comment: I have to try this, had to stop working on it for a while, but this sounds a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This link tells you how to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode (provided you're using the Grub bootloader):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

If that doesn't work then you can always create a live CD/USB from another machine and boot up with that to recover your system.  If you don't know how to do that I can post links to some useful resources.

---

UPDATE: The Linux/Ubuntu on Tegra K1 Jetson board is alightly different than the one used by desktop and laptops.

Comment: Thanks, but the shift does not seems to work to bring the grub menu,I am looking for a Serial cable, that might help me to connect to the unit using a terminal.

Comment: Oh, I see ... it's a development board that came with Ubuntu pre-installed.  Maybe it's not quite as simple as plugging in a live USB then :-)

Comment: Yes, I finally got it to stop after repeatedly hitting space, escape and all other keys, and re-installed Ubuntu and the problem is solved.

Comment: Cool - glad you got it to work.  Still a bit of a mystery as to what was causing it though.

Comment: Too quick to cheer, after a day of working properly, it stopped working again.This is well known problem with the version of Ubuntu that comes with the Tegra K1 Jetson board. It is really annoying, now I can not even get to the prompt any more, got to bring back the serial cable again.